# Serving static content in microservice architecture

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, nginx, microservices

I'm building web application in microservice architecture and we decided to build it on top of `Spring Boot` with `Spring Cloud` and deployment on AWS on Docker containers with S3 as image storage and RDS for data.

My current concern is regarding serving a static content such as HTML, JS.

In microservices the popular solution is to use API Gateway as a single point of entry, so how I should serve mentioned files? In the beginning I thought that having NGINX in front would be helpful so it'd load balance, route to all services and serve static content. But if we choose to use `Spring Cloud Gateway` instead of NGINX as a gateway, then how to serve? Beside the fact NGINX and Spring Gateway have the same purpose the NGINX is more than simply a gateway, as far as I understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply serve files direct from S3 so long as your webapp is built so that cross-domain issues do not affect Javascript. (Enabling CORS in S3 can help.)

Comment: It sounds good, but if I would like to change cloud provider to Azure then I would have to implement similar solution on S3 equivalent, right? Even more questions, but I guess having a completly generic solution is not an option, unless we would use terraform?

Comment: No need to change cloud provider. S3 files are simply served from a URL--they can be accessed from anywhere.